# Error: Field 'wLanguage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter3.x

When running the `flutter build appbundle` command, I get the following error :

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/package_info_plus_windows-2.1.0/lib/src/file_version_info.dart:13:17: 
Error: Field 'wLanguage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external int? wLanguage;
                ^

../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/package_info_plus_windows-2.1.0/lib/src/file_version_info.dart:16:17: 
Error: Field 'wCodePage' cannot be nullable or have type 'Null', it must be `int`, `double`, `Pointer`, or a subtype of `Struct` or `Union`.
  external int? wCodePage;
                ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I am using Flutter 3.10.0. The project was running fine before I updated the flutter version.

Comment: have you tried `upgrading` the error causing plugin?

Comment: The `package_info_plus windows` plugin is used internally by flutter I have no control over that I guess.

Comment: On the other hand, I updated all the packages in `pubspec.yaml` but the error still exists.

Comment: tried clean command? sometimes cache makes a nuisance. If you upgraded flutter for any other reason than necessity(other package or functionality requirements ) i suppose you could downgrade for now. It might be a bug in that version

Comment: Ah, I see you also recently upgraded to flutter 3.10 :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I finally fix my problem by overriding these packages in my project's `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  package_info_plus: ^4.0.1
  wakelock_windows: any
  win32: any
```

or

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  package_info_plus: any
```

---

Overriding the `package_info_plus`  to  `^4.0.1`  gave me the following error message because of my project dependencies.

> Because no versions of wakelock_windows match >0.2.1 <0.3.0 and wakelock_windows <0.2.1 depends on win32 ^2.0.0, wakelock_windows <0.2.1-∞ or >0.2.1 <0.3.0 requires win32 ^2.0.0.
> And because wakelock_windows 0.2.1 depends on win32 ^3.0.0, wakelock_windows <0.3.0 requires win32 ^2.0.0 or ^3.0.0.
> And because package_info_plus >=4.0.1 depends on win32 >=4.0.0 <6.0.0 and wakelock 0.6.2 depends on wakelock_windows ^0.2.0, package_info_plus >=4.0.1 is incompatible with wakelock 0.6.2.
> Because chewie >=1.3.5 depends on wakelock ^0.6.2 and no versions of wakelock match >0.6.2 <0.7.0, chewie >=1.3.5 requires wakelock 0.6.2.
> Thus, package_info_plus >=4.0.1 is incompatible with chewie >=1.3.5.
> So, because start depends on both chewie ^1.4.0 and package_info_plus ^4.0.1, version solving failed.

If you have a similar message after overriding the `package_info_plus`, you can check the dependent packages and add them to `dependency_overrides` and set the version to `any` as in my above example.

---

The `Any` keyword can be used to specify that *any version of a package is acceptable*. This can be useful if you want to make sure that your app is compatible with the latest version of a package, or if you want to avoid breaking changes that may be introduced in a future version of a package.

Answer (score 12):

I had same issue and I solved mine by going into my
file_version_info file and made them not nullable.

Example: From this:

```
class _LANGANDCODEPAGE extends Struct {
  @Uint16()
  external int? wLanguage;

  @Uint16()
  external int? wCodePage;
}
```

to this:

```
class _LANGANDCODEPAGE extends Struct {
  @Uint16()
  external int wLanguage;

  @Uint16()
  external int wCodePage;
}
```

you can find this file in

/Users/name/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/package_info_plus_windows-2.1.0/lib/src/file_version_info.dart

I hope this helps.

Comment: NIce one this actually fixed the error for me

Answer (score 5):

For me was flutter screen utils and google font

i did first is type

`flutter pub upgrade` or   `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`

then i change my ext.kotlin to latest in android folder then build gradle to

`ext.kotlin = '1.6.20`' to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.21'`

then i able to run my project i hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, its work for me and error fixed

Answer (score 5):

In order to fix this issue you will open file_version_info.dart
from your path

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/package_info_plus_windows 2.1.0/lib/src/file_version_info.dart
```

and search about `int? wCodePage;` and `int? wLanguage;` then remove `?`.

Comment: Glad to help @yaldamohasseli

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
flutter pub remove package_info_plus
flutter pub add package_info_plus
```

This deletes the outdated packages:

```
These packages are no longer being depended on:
- package_info_plus 1.4.3+1
- package_info_plus_linux 1.0.5
- package_info_plus_macos 1.3.0
- package_info_plus_platform_interface 1.0.2
- package_info_plus_web 1.0.6
- package_info_plus_windows 2.1.0
Changed 6 dependencies!
```

Then it adds the new packages back in - without adding the outdated ones

```
+ package_info_plus 4.1.0
+ package_info_plus_platform_interface 2.0.1
> win32 5.0.6 (was 3.1.4)
```

I think what really happened here is that the package changed and didn't need these additional platform specific files anymore, but the package manager can't quite handle this change and doesn't remove the stale packages.

The stale package package_info_plus_windows then causes the error.

When we remove the package, it removes all dependencies correctly.

When we then add the package back in, it adds the new dependencies correctly.

Problem solved.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer! It fixed the problem for me without having to do any `dependency_overrides` or changing the `file_version_info.dart` file. Seems like the best solution! Thanks for the solution and great explanation @n13

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue but after reading carefully the logs, I added this part in pub spec file

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
    package_info_plus: any
```

I needed also to update the `firebase/auth` packages to `10.9`. I run this command -->
`pod update Firebase/Auth`

Answer (score 3):

I've worked on this error for 2 days: my solution (but is not the best solution) is to update the 'file_version_info.dart' with:

```
class _LANGANDCODEPAGE extends Struct {
  @Uint16()
  external int wLanguage;

  @Uint16()
  external int wCodePage;
}
```

and remove the int?

It works.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply fix this problem by overriding the dependency, put the following code in your pubspec.yaml and that would fix your problem:

```
dependency_overrides:
 package_info_plus_windows: 3.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to pubspec.yaml should resolve the issue

```
dependency_overrides:
 package_info_plus: ^4.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

i had this error after upgrading flutter,
just run "dart pub upgrade"

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem.

In my case related to flutter_app_version_checker.
version 0.3.2 has dependency to old package_info_plus_x packages.

Somebody already PR the fix for flutter_app_version_checker, but package does not releases..

So I fork the repo and apply fix for my project.

```yaml
  # from
dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.4
  package_info_plus: ^1.4.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

  # to
dependencies:
  http: ^0.13.6
  package_info_plus: ^4.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
```

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
....
 flutter_app_version_checker:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:kevin-chnp/app_version_checker.git
...
(you can use your own repo)
```